# jQuery dotdotdot not working with calc

Tags: jquery, css, css-calc

Applying calc to a width of a containing div stops the jQuery dotdotdot plugin from working.

```css
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
div#outer {
    width: calc(100% - 1px);
}
div#inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nec tortor consequat, facilisis arcu iaculis, congue orci. Duis in dui augue. Nullam ultricies arcu ante, vitae iaculis ipsum hendrerit eu.</div>
</div>
```

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tuckerconnelly/KEqrL/2/)

Can someone help find a fix or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KEqrL/6/)</kbd>

You need to specify the div to use. You can't use all divs like you did.

```
$(function () {
    $('#inner').dotdotdot();
});
```

Note that you can also use Ellipsis CSS property to avoid overflow (but you can't add automatically a text like "read more" or other stuffs that dotdotdot offers) : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp